# Where can I find Wujeeta in Riften?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been trying to become Thane in Riften, and, in order to do this, I have to find Wujeeta to start the Skooma Trade Quest. I looked online and found that she might be in Helga's Bunker or at the fishery. However, I haven't been able to find her.

Is there another place where she might be, or is there a glitch in the game?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never played Skyrim but I could find something that may be usefull for you:

> Well, I read today on elderscrolls wikia that I have to complete the Civil War questline first. I was wondering if this was true as I've only played that line up through the conquering of Whiterun (I'm on the Stormcloak side).

and he replies to himself:

> Well, I decided after not finding her to go way back to one of my earliest saves in the game, right after escaping Helgen), went to Whiterun to get a carriage to Riften right away and she was there in the docks around the fishery. Sadly, that means all the hours of grinding I did need to be redone now, but I can get all the houses. My advice to anyone first starting the game, go to Riften as early as you can (before any other quests, inclunding the main story questline) and start the Skooma quest you get from talking to Wujeeta 2 times before doing anything else in order to lock in the chance of getting Honeyside as early as possible.

More than this, all I could find was:

> Do you have a quest (miscellaneous or otherwise) that directs you to Wujeeta? And if so, is there a quest marker? If not, then it's possible that they are dead, or otherwise glitched.

and, of course:

> Maybe she got clipped into a surface and was sent to the void, the game has a nasty sense of humor when that happens, so she might be lost forever.

Hope it was helpfull.

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/ps3/615804-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/answers/325333-help-cant-locate-wujeeta-is-she-dead)

Comment: I edited the question providing all I could find.

Comment: Thank you. I guess it might be that she is either dead or has glitched. I'll look elsewhere for a suitable house. Thank you.